# Caching relational data using redis

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, social-networking

I'm building a small social network (users have posts and posts have comments - very basic), using clustered nodejs server and redis as a distributed cache. 

 My approach to cache users posts is to have a `sorted set` that contains all the user's posts ids ordered by rate(which should be updated every time someone add a like or comment), and actual objects sorted as `hash objects`. 
So the get user's posts flow should look like this: 
 
 1. using `zrange` to get a range of ids from the `sorted set`. 
 2. using `multi/exec` and `hgetall` to fetch all the objects at once.

I have a couple of questions: 

1. in regards of performance issues, will my approach scale when the cache size getting bigger, or maybe I should use lua or something? 
 1. in case if I want to continue with current approach, where I should save the sorted set in case of redis crash, if I use the redis persistence this will affect the overall performance, I thought about using a dedicated redis server for the `sets` (I searched If it is possible to backup only part of the redis data but didn't found anything about it.

My approach => getTopObjects({userID}, 0, 20) :

```
self.zrange = function(setID, start, stop, multi)
{
    return execute(this, "zrange", [setID, start, stop], multi);
};

self.getObject = function(key, multi)
{
    return execute(this, "hgetall", key, multi);
};

self.getObjects = function(keys)
{
    let multi = thisArg.client.multi();
    let promiseArray = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        promiseArray.push(this.getObject(keys[i], multi));
    }
    return execute(this, "exec", [], multi).then(function(results)
    {
        //TODO: do something with the result.
        return Promise.all(promiseArray);
    });
};

self.getTopObjects = function(setID, start, stop)
{
    //TODO: validate the range 
    let thisArg = this;
    return this.zrevrange(setID, start, stop).then(function(keys)
    {
        return thisArg.getObjects(keys);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting intellectual exercise, but in my opinion this is classic [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

1) It's probably way too early to have even *introduced* redis, let alone be thinking about whether redis is fast enough. Your social network is almost certainly just fine up to about 1,000 users running off raw SQL queries against Mysql / Postgres / Random RDS. If it starts to slow down, get data on slow running queries and fix them with query optimizations and appropriate indexes. That'll get you past 10,000 users.

2) Now you can start introducing redis. In *general*, I'd encourage you to think about your redis as purely caching and not permanent storage; it shouldn't matter if it gets blown away, it just means your site is slower for the next few seconds because your users are getting their page loads from SQL queries instead of redis hits (each query re-populating that user's sorted list of posts in redis, of course).

Your strategy and example code for using redis seem fine to me, but until you have actual data on how users *use* your site (which may be drastically different than your current expectations), it's simply impossible to know what types of SQL indexes you will need, what keys and lists are ideal for caching in redis, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issues, I needed a way to query the data more efficiently. Can't say for sure but I heard [Redis](https://redis.io/) being single threaded blocks the main thread when running lua scripts, i'm sure that's not good for a social networking site. I heard about [Tarantool](https://www.tarantool.io/en/developers/) and it looks promising, currently trying to wrap my head around it.

If you are concerned about your cache size growing bigger, I think most social networks keep two weeks worth of data in the users cache, anything older than two weeks gets deleted and you simply implement a scrolling feature that works with pagination, once the user scrolls down, fetch the next two weeks worth of data and add it back to memory only for that specific user (don't forget to specify the new ttl for the newly added data). This helps keep your cache size lean.

What happens when redis or any in memory data tool you are using crashes, you simply reload data back into the memory. They all have features where you save data to files as backup. I'm thinking of implementing another database layer don't know lets say [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) or [Mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/) that holds the timelines of each user since inception. Sure this creates another overhead cause you have to keep three data layers (e.g mysql, redis and mongodb) in sync!

If this looks like a lot of work, feel free to use a 3rd party service to host your in memory data, at least you can sleep easy, but it's gonna cost you.

That said, this is highly opinionated. Got tired of people telling me to wait until my site explodes with users or the so called [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) reply you got :)